# throwing error while creating UserCredential ;

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-api

I am getting the error as :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or
>   one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was
>   invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

while executing the code for integrating google calendar in my web site using google API v3:

the code is:

```
     public bool connectCalendar()
        {
            ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "10xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx82.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "LxxxxxxxxxxxXYEb3Iaxo3C"
            };
            CalendarService calendarConnection;                try
            {
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, new string[]{
                    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar}, "user",
                    CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary")).Result;
//exception is thrown in this line
                var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
                initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
                initializer.ApplicationName = "secret-heaven-798";
                calendarConnection = new CalendarService(initializer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

am referring this [link](http://blog.bigbasti.com/retrieving-calendar-events-using-google-calendar-api/), why am getting this error? what am doing wrong?

i had add these line to the web config file:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" PublicKeyToken="7cec85d7bea7798e" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Please write a better title instead of your error message. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title

Comment: please don't forget to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

One of components of your solution is dependent on System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0. This assembly should be in bin directory of you solution (I don't know is it web, or win or etc) or in the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx). Most likely you don't have this assembly on your environment.